# Перенос строки после N символа в c#

Tags: c#, .net

Видел примеры на различных языках, но для c# не понял как это реализовать, прошу помощи. Есть текст, к примеру 20 символов. Как сделать перенос строки после 10 символов к примеру? Спасибо.

Comment: а на других языках как это реализовывалось?:)

Comment: @Grundy если вы знаете ответ, почему бы вам просто не помочь мне?

Comment: `Regex.Replace(str, "(?<=\\G.{10})(?=.)", "\n")`

Comment: @PetSerAl, насколько эффективен предпросмотр назад?

Comment: @Qwertiy На шесть целых и пять десятых.

Comment: внезапный codegolf?

Answer (score 5):

Самый простой в плане скорости написания кода способ - использовать регулярные выражения: http://ideone.com/rbR09w

```
public static string SplitToLines(string str, int n)
{
  return Regex.Replace(str, ".{"+n+"}(?!$)", "$0\n");
}
```

Comment: Самый правильный код, на мой взгляд)

Answer (score 3):

Ещё такой вариант:

```
string text = "абвгдеёжзиийклмн";
int k = 10, i = text.Length;
text = text.Substring(0, k) + "\n" + text.Substring(k+1, i-k-1);
```

By [tym32167](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/179763/tym32167):

```
text = text.Substring(0, k) + Environment.NewLine + text.Substring(k + 1, i - k - 1);
```

Comment: А если там больше двух строк?

Comment: @Qwertiy автор вопроса спросил про перенос в единственном числе

Comment: Хм.. Не обратил внимания на этот момент. Тогда да, хорошее решение :)

Comment: Реквестирую замену ```\n``` на ```Environment.NewLine``` :)

Answer (score 2):

Хороший в плене производительности способ - StringBuilder: http://ideone.com/Mmnvjp

```
public static string SplitToLines(string str, int n)
{
  var sb = new StringBuilder(str.Length + (str.Length + 9) / 10);

  for (int q=0; q<str.Length; )
  {
    sb.Append(str[q]);

    if (++q % n == 0)
      sb.AppendLine();
  }

  if (str.Length % n == 0)
    --sb.Length;

  return sb.ToString();
}
```

Comment: ну зачем так то. insert в строку после нужного символа ни кто не отменял

Comment: @rdorn, Insert в StringBuilder'е будет двигать весь хвост каждый раз, а в строке - вообще копировать всю строку. Асимптотика в обоих случаях будет квадратичная, а в мойм решении - линейная.

Comment: надо в исходники залезть... не думаю что там так уж все плохо, хотя... короче полез смотреть

Comment: https://referencesource.microsoft.com/mscorlib/R/61f8c55c63613daf.html во. Там тоже линейная скорость, причем похоже, что само копирование использует неуправляемый код. В случае множественной вставки (каждые N знаков) я бы тоже применил такой вариант, но для одиночного случая, лучше родной инсерт

Comment: @rdorn, копирование неуправляемым кодом всё равно копирует всю строку. Со строками точно квадратичная асимптотика. Вот с новой реализацией StringBuilder'а на связных списках - возможно не квадратичная, но всё равно что-то будет на каждой итерации двигаться.

Comment: под одиночным случаем я имел ввиду единственную вставку в строку. А что за новая реализация, где почитать? И не посадят ли производительность накладные на инфраструктуру связного списка?

Comment: @rdorn, про единственную согласен. А почитать вот: https://habrahabr.ru/post/172689/

Answer (score 2):

Такой вариант...

```
using static System.Console;

class Program
{
    public static string Insert_LF_n(string s, int n)
    {
        char[] c = new char[s.Length + s.Length / n];

        int i = 0, j = 1;

        foreach(char ch in s)
        {
            c[i++] = ch;

            if(j++ % n == 0)
            {
                c[i++] = '\n';
                j = 1;
            }
        }

        // если последний символ - "перевод строки" - удаляем.
        if (c[i - 1] == '\n')
            i--;

        return new string(c, 0, i);
    }



    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string s = "kjabdjlirujl;qkmrghwiureh;alksngk;jhdriughjksndv.ma'pjkrdoigkdfjnvsdlkjfp'iowjoeijrlkdjflk";

        WriteLine(s);
        Write('\n' + Insert_LF_n(s, 10));

        ReadKey();
    }
}
```

Comment: Если длина строки кратна 10, то добавляется лишний перевод строки в конец. А так, мне нравится :)

Comment: Теперь удаляет перевод строки)

Comment: Протестировал время выполнения, StringBuilder самый быстрый:
Время выполнения 100000 повторов функции:
Insert_LF_n(через массив char[]): 221 мс,    
SplitToLinesByQwertiy(Regex): 664 мс,   
SplitToLinesByChloroform(StringBuilder): 156 мс

Comment: Странно. По идее массив должен быть быстрее.

Comment: @Qwertiy, видно там машинный код.
Результаты среднего времени за 10 проходов, + StringBuilderByQwertiy:
Insert_LF_n(через массив char[]): 192 мс  
SplitToLinesByQwertiy(Regex): 644 мс  
SplitToLinesByChloroform(StringBuilder): 145 мс  
SplitToLinesStringBuilderByQwertiy(StringBuilder): 243 мс

Comment: Дополню...
Предыдущие результаты были для строки длиной 90 символов.
Попробовал для строки 900 символов и получил интересные результаты)                Insert_LF_n(через массив char[]): 2050 мс      
SplitToLinesByQwertiy(Regex): 5148 мс      
SplitToLinesByChloroform(StringBuilder): 2691 мс      
SplitToLinesStringBuilderByQwertiy(StringBuilder): 2673 мс     Массив быстрее) и методы со StringBuilder-ми поменялись местами...8)

Comment: Для 4500 символов - 10000 повторов:1059 мс, 2570 мс, 2687 мс, 1344 мс

Answer (score 1):

```
string myString = "My very long string.......................................";
string rn = Environment.NewLine;
int offset = 10;
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(myString);
for (int i = 1; i <= myString.Length / offset; i++)
{
    sb.Insert(i * offset + (i - 1) * rn.Length, rn);
}
Console.WriteLine(sb.ToString());
```

Сделал через `StringBuilder`, должен лучше работать при очень большой длине строки.

Answer (score 0):

Как-то так получилось

```
int countOnOneLine = 10;
string testStr = "123456789D123456789D1111";
string resultStr = "";

for (int i = 1; i <= testStr.Length; i++)
{
    if (i % countOnOneLine == 0)
        resultStr += testStr[i - 1] + Environment.NewLine;
    else
        resultStr += testStr[i - 1];
}

Console.WriteLine(resultStr);
Console.ReadLine();
```

ПС: что-то мне подсказывает что есть и поадекватней решение...

Comment: StringBuilder...

Answer (score 0):

Стартуем цикл с начальной позиции и каждый раз вставляем необходимую строку. Сдвигаемся на 10 + размер вставленной строки. И т.д.

Использование:

```
var result = InsertEach(source, Environment.NewLine, 10);
```

Метод:

```
public static string InsertEach(string source, string insertValue, int interval)
{
    var lengthOfNewLine = insertValue.Length;
    for (var i = interval; i < source.Length; i += interval + lengthOfNewLine)
    {
        source = source.Insert(i, insertValue);
    }

    return source;
}
```

[Тестить](https://dotnetfiddle.net/qjqeWE)!

Comment: И тут квадратичная асимптотика.

Comment: @Qwertiy, а у замены через регэкспы какая асимптотика?

Comment: @Андрей, не знаю. Думаю, саму замену они оптимизировали, поэтому в моём варианте получится линейная с довольно жирными накладными расходами. А вот регулярку из комеентария (ту, в которой предпросмотр назад) оценить не могу.

Answer (score 0):

Моя версия Regex)

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(Regex());
        Console.WriteLine(Iteration());
        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    static string Regex()
    {
        string pattern = @"(.{0,10})";
        string input = "qwertyuiopqqwertyuiopqwertyuiopwertyuio";
        string replacement = "$1\n";
        Regex rgx = new Regex(pattern);
        string result = rgx.Replace(input, replacement);
        return result;
    }

    static string Iteration()
    {
        int n = 10;
        string input = "qwertyuiopqqwertyuiopqwertyuiopwertyuio";
        for (int i = n; i < input.Length; i += n + 1)
        {
            input = input.Insert(i, "\n");
        }
        return input;
    }
```

Comment: В regex баг: если длина строки будет кратна 10, то в конец тоже добавится перевод строки, хотя по идее не должен.

Comment: Как посмотреть... Условию удовлетворяет)